# event.Invoke(args) vs event(args). Which is faster?

Tags: c#, .net

Which is faster; using `event.Invoke(args)`, or just calling `event(args)`. What's the difference? Is one faster or slower than the other; or is it just a matter of preference?

Comment: Did you try it yourself? Profile it and see which one performs better?

Comment: There doesn't 'seem' to be any difference when it's just a few clients, but I'm concerned about what might happen when I scale it up. I have to make the decision before I publish it in our new product, when one computer might potentially be dealing with thousands of network connections at once.

Comment: It would be nice if someone could explain what the difference is in the way the two methods are implemented.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Writing `someDelegate(...)` is a compiler shorthand for `someDelegate.Invoke(...)`.
They both compile to the same IL—a `callvirt` instruction to that delegate type's `Invoke` method.

The `Invoke` method is generated by the compiler for each concrete delegate type.

By contrast, the `DynamicInvoke` method, defined on the base `Delegate` type, uses reflection to call the delegate and is slow.

Answer (score 38):

Since the introduction of [null-conditionals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) in C# 6.0, `Invoke` can be used to simplify thread-safe null-checking of delegates. Where you would previously have to do something like

```
var handler = event;
if (handler != null)
    handler(args);
```

the combination of `?.` and `Invoke` allows you to simply write

```
event?.Invoke(args)
```

Answer (score 15):

When you call `event(args)`, the C# compiler turns it into an IL call for `event.Invoke(args)`.  It's the same thing - like using `string` or `System.String`.

Answer (score 9):

Both ways end up generating exactly the same IL, so there isn't any difference in calling them.

That being said, if you have performance problems, changes like this aren't likely to help you much, if at all.