# What is the difference between these possibilities to raise an event in C#?

Tags: c#, events, raise, raiseevent

Imagine an event

```
private event EventHandler SampleEvent;
```

which should be raised. I know 3 ways to do this, but I don't get the difference between two of them which are

```
SampleEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

and

```
SampleEvent.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

What is the difference between those two and what advantages and disadvantages does either method have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5928119/261050

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since event is represented by a delegate internally, `Invoke` method is present there. Omitting it in calling is just a compiler trick to have a more readable code.