# How can i Use a Event as method in C# windows form?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, forms, windows-forms-designer

```
 this.FormClosing();
```

i want to Use C# windows form Event like a method but will say "the Event 'Form.FormClosing'can appear on the left hand side of += of -=".what should i do?!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manually invoke an event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8734700/how-to-manually-invoke-an-event) and [Calling an event handler in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12217632/calling-an-event-handler-in-c-sharp) and [event.Invoke(args) vs event(args). Which is faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5928077/event-invokeargs-vs-eventargs-which-is-faster)

Answer (score -1):

I think you should provide a little more information about what you're trying to accomplish. What logic are you trying to run?

Essentially, Form.FormClosing ([MSDN Form.FormClosing Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.formclosing?view=net-5.0)) is declared as an event, not a method. So in order to assign logic to run when that event occurs, you need to wire an event handler to it.

```
this.FormClosing += OnFormClosing;

private void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    // Logic to be performed as the form closes
}
```

See: [How to add or remove an event handler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-add-an-event-handler?view=netdesktop-5.0)

If you're trying to invoke the event outside of it's natural invocation path (ie when the form is closing), you can do try something like this:

```
if (this.FormClosing != null) this.FormClosing.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);

// Or null shorthand:

this.FormClosing?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
```

[How to raise and consume events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/how-to-raise-and-consume-events)

But.. if you want to run the logic that would run with the window closes, you can just move it to its own method, and run that.

```
this.FormClosing += OnFormClosing;

private void OnFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    MyWindowClosingLogic(true);
}

private void MyWindowClosingLogic(bool isClosing = false)
{
    if (!isClosing)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The logic is being run, but the window is not closing...");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The Window is closing");
    }
}

private void SomeOtherMethod()
{
    MyWindowClosingLogic();
}
```